# SQLITE - calculate remaining item quantities

Tags: sqlite, subtraction

I have a stock table that holds the number of total items for a specific item id/colour:

**stock_table**

```
    item_code    |    colour    |    stock
---------------------------------------------
       A         |    red       |    10
       A         |    blue      |    8
       A         |    yellow    |    5
       B         |    red       |    5
       B         |    blue      |    0
       B         |    yellow    |    15
```

then I have a table where already ordered items quantities are stored (note that the same item can be found in different orders)

**orders_table**

```
    order_id     |    item_code    |    colour    |    ordered_qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       1         |        A        |     red      |        3
       1         |        A        |     blue     |        1
       1         |        A        |     yellow   |        2
       1         |        B        |     red      |        1
       2         |        A        |     red      |        1
       2         |        A        |     yellow   |        3
       2         |        B        |     yellow   |        15
```

I need to create a table that holds the remaining stock quantities available: for example for each item's qty in the stock table, I need to subtract the "already ordered" qty from orders table, to get something like this:

**remaining_table**

```
    item_code    |    colour    |    remaining
------------------------------------------------
       A         |    red       |    6
       A         |    blue      |    7
       A         |    yellow    |    0
       B         |    red       |    4
       B         |    blue      |    0
       B         |    yellow    |    0
```

I was thinking of using a view, as the table will auto update for every new inserted order row. I'm able to get the "already ordered" quantities for each item/colour:

```
SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(stock) as already_placed FROM orders_table GROUP BY item_code, colour
```

this query will return something like (note that B/blue has never been ordered):

```
    item_code    |    colour    |    already_placed
----------------------------------------------------
       A         |    red       |    4
       A         |    blue      |    1
       A         |    yellow    |    5
       B         |    red       |    1
       B         |    yellow    |    15
```

Now I'm stuck on building the query that will give me, in a table or in another view, the **remaining_table quantities**..

long story short, I need to subtract from the original **stock_table** the **already_placed** quantities, can you please help me? I can't find any "minus" or "subtract" function here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

is it possible to do?

Thanks in advance, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery to compute how many specific items have been ordered:

```
CREATE VIEW remaining_view AS
SELECT item_code,
       colour,
       stock - (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ordered_qty), 0)
                FROM orders_table
                WHERE orders_table.item_code = stock_table.item_code
                  AND orders_table.colour    = stock_table.colour)
       AS remaining
FROM stock_table
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/88e13/2)

Answer (score 1):

You could UNION the `stock_table` and the `orders_table`, but in the `orders_table` you change the sign of `ordered_qty`. Then you `group by`

Something like

```
SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(stock) as remaining FROM
(
    SELECT item_code, colour, stock FROM stock_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item_code, colour, -ordered_qty as stock FROM orders_table
)
GROUP BY item_code, colour
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/27155/1

Other option

```
SELECT sto.item_code, sto.colour, sto.in_stock - COALESCE(ord.already_placed, 0) AS remaining 
    FROM
        (SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(stock) AS in_stock FROM stock_table GROUP BY item_code, colour) sto
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(ordered_qty) AS already_placed FROM orders_table GROUP BY item_code, colour) ord
        ON ord.item_code = sto.item_code AND ord.colour = sto.colour
```

Here the `SELECT` of `sto` and `ord` could be put in two views (one with the total of the stock ordered and one with the total of the stock in stock.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d78d7/13

Answer (score 1):

You can use natural left join:

```
SELECT item_code, colour, IFNULL(q_stock - q_ordered, 0) as remaining
FROM (SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(stock) as q_stock FROM stock_table GROUP BY item_code, colour)
 NATURAL LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT item_code, colour, SUM(ordered_qty) as q_ordered FROM orders_table GROUP BY item_code, colour)
```