# Get remaining items in store

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a table like:

```
itemid | remaining_quantity
-------|---------
1      | 100
-------|---------
3      | 150
-------|---------
4      | 300
```

Significant tables:

- Purshase (id, itemid, quantity, isReceived) // is received by us?
- Sale (id, itemid, quantity, isReceived) // is received by customer?
- Item (id, init_quantity)
- LostItem (id, itemid, quantity) // this is used to fix actual quantity if it is actually increased or decreased

As you can see, we should only consider those sales and purshases where `isReceived = True`. In `LostItem`, quantity may be negative, means that actual quantity is less than calculated quantity. It can be positive too, means the actual is more that calculated.

(i.e. I want to get Purshase - Sale + LostItem + item)

Here what I have done so far: (results in no rows)

```
select i.itemid, 
      isnull(sum(p.quantity), 0) - isnull(sum(s.quantity), 0)
        + isnull(sum(t.quantity), 0) + isnull(sum(i.itemInitQuantity), 0)
    as remaining_quantity
from [Purshase] p, [Sale] s, [LostItem] t, [Item] i
where p.pitem = i.itemid and s.saleitem = i.itemid and t.item = i.itemid
      and p.isReceived = 1 and s.isReceived = 1
group by i.itemid
```

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011962/sqlite-calculate-remaining-item-quantities

Comment: is your formula for remaining quantity is right?  As I can understand it should be like init_quantity - toatl purchase - total sale - total lost.

Comment: @Mukund Yes you are right

Comment: but lost should be `+` not `-`, because its value maybe nagetive. Lost maybe increase quantity than calculated (i.e. not lost but someone added items to store)

Comment: Can you put in sample data for all the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!! (Alhamdu lellah)

```
SELECT itemid, init, sales_all, sales_mostlma, purchases_all,
purchases_mstlma, taswiyah, sales_mardood, purchases_mardood, 
sales_request, pruchases_request,init - sales_mostlma + purchases_mstlma + 
taswiyah + sales_mardood - purchases_mardood AS stock, init - sales_all + 
purchases_all + taswiyah + sales_mardood - purchases_mardood AS available, 
init - sales_all + purchases_all + taswiyah + sales_mardood - 
purchases_mardood -  sales_request + pruchases_request 
AS available_with_request
FROM (SELECT itemid,itemInitQuantity AS init,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(salequantity), 0) AS cnt FROM dbo.Sale AS s
WHERE (saleitem = i.itemid) AND (tasleemTime IS NOT NULL)) AS sales_mostlma,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(salequantity), 0) AS cnt FROM dbo.Sale AS s
WHERE (saleitem = i.itemid)) AS sales_all,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(pcquantity), 0) AS cnt FROM dbo.Purshase AS p
WHERE (pitem = i.itemid) AND (tasleemTime IS NOT NULL)) AS purchases_mstlma,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(pcquantity), 0) AS cnt FROM dbo.Purshase AS p
WHERE (pitem = i.itemid)) AS purchases_all, 
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(quantity), 0) AS cnt FROM dbo.TaswiyahGardiyah AS t
WHERE (item = i.itemid)) AS taswiyah,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(sm.smquantity), 0) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.SaleMardood AS sm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sale AS ss ON sm.smsale = ss.saleid
WHERE (ss.saleitem = i.itemid)) AS sales_mardood,
(SELECT        ISNULL(SUM(pm.purmquantity), 0) AS Expr1 
FROM dbo.PurshaseMardood AS pm 
INNER JOIN dbo.Purshase AS pur ON pm.purmpurshase = pur.pid
WHERE (pur.pitem = i.itemid)) AS purchases_mardood,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(prquantity), 0) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.PurshaseRequest AS pr
WHERE (pritem = i.itemid)) AS pruchases_request,
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(scquantity), 0) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.SaleRequest AS sr
WHERE (scitem = i.itemid)) AS sales_request
FROM dbo.Item AS i) AS myTable
```